# Live tuning of Tomcat 7 memory settings

Tags: centos, vps, tomcat7

I know I can change `bin/setenv.sh`, but is it possible to apply new settings without restarting Tomcat? Specifically can I extend maximum heap size (Xmx) somehow?

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot increase `Xmx` on the fly. What you can do is to increase the value of `Xmx` in the config file and start another tomcat instance if your application don't mind that.